# Security Patch SUPEE-8788 problem : SUPEE-3941 can't apply

Tags: ee-1.13, supee-8788

I have Magento ver. 1.13.0.2.
I try to apply the security patch SUPEE-8788.

I have revert the SUPEE-1533, but I don't succeed to apply the SUPEE-3941.

But I don't understand the issue. There is no 'hunk failed', only "can't find file to patch at input line xxx" :

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
|index 77c971e..d62cabc 100644
|--- downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
|+++ downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Backup.php
can't find file to patch at input line 195
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command.php downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command.php
|index 6056028..fad7aa0 100644
|--- downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command.php
|+++ downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 244
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Install.php downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Install.php
|index 549e730..20aa691 100644
|--- downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Install.php
|+++ downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Install.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 314
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php
|index 3519324..09ea41b 100644
|--- downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php
|+++ downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
10 out of 10 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 504
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php
|index 981c99a..d7366c3 100644
|--- downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php
|+++ downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 528
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Singleconfig.php downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Singleconfig.php
|index 450c04e..7dfaaf1 100644
|--- downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Singleconfig.php
|+++ downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Singleconfig.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 540
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Validator.php downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Validator.php
|index 384274b..fcb4198 100644
|--- downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Validator.php
|+++ downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Validator.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 566
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
|index bc3685f..1d0833c 100644
|--- downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
|+++ downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 705
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git downloader/template/settings.phtml downloader/template/settings.phtml
|index b094d4d..83e3987 100755
|--- downloader/template/settings.phtml
|+++ downloader/template/settings.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

Then, if I wan't to apply the SUPEE-8788, I get :

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
[...]
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml.rej
[...]
```

Someone have an idea how to resolve it ?

Thank you for any tips !

EDIT :

I succeed to apply SUPEE-3941. The downloader directory was deleted previously. I restored it and that works. I confused paths because, for exemple, this file exists : lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php but this file not : downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php

But applying the patch SUPEE-8788 doesn't work. Here the output :

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Redirect/Select/Category/Tree.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/ImportExport/Model/Scheduled/Operation.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/Block/Adminhtml/Invitation/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/Block/Adminhtml/Invitation/View.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Processor.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 709 (offset 5 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pbridge/Model/Pbridge/Api/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pbridge/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pbridge/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pci/Model/Encryption.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Controller/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design/Images.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/enterprise/invitation/view/tab/general.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 26.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/review/form.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/iphone/template/wishlist/view.phtml
patching file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv.rej
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file downloader/Maged/Controller.php.rej
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php.rej
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 154.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/Maged/View.php.rej
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml.rej
patching file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
patching file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/enterprise/boxes.css
```

Comment: before applying SUPEE-8788 patch we need to apply SUPEE-3941, If it hasn't already applied. but when trying to apply PATCH_SUPEE-3941_EE_1.14.0.1_v1-2016-10-14-09-02-41.sh patch giving error

Comment: Do you get the same issue ?

Comment: based on your EDIT i too applied SUPEE-3941 and it is success. When i try to apply SUPEE-8788 patch giving different output than yours

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Sorry, but I don't remember how I solved this issue..